# Incrementar um "property path" em um ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso incrementar um `property path` em um `ajax`, preciso adicionar números na frente da propriedade em um for e receber o valor dela, segue exemplo:

```
data.data[0].genero1
```

Preciso pegar o `genero2` agora, tentei isso mas não funcionou:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var p = "genero"+i;
    console.log(p);
    console.log(data.data[0].p);
}
```

Esse `for` acima não dá erro, mas retorna `undefined`

A `var p` retorna a string corretamente, o segundo `console.log` que dá `undefined`

Comment: Porque o "-1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue exemplo:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var p = "genero"+i;
    console.log(p);
    console.log(data.data[0][p]);
}
```